# Find $\int_0^{\infty} x\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) y \, dx$ where $xy''+y'-xy=0, y(0)=1, y'(0) = 0.$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $y$ is the unique solution to the IVP $xy''+y'-xy=0, y(0)=1, y'(0) = 0,$ how can we compute $\int_0^{\infty} x\cos\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right) y \, dx$?

Integration by parts seems like a good idea given that we can use the fact that $(xy')' = xy$ to take $dv=xy \, dx, u = \cos(x/\sqrt{2}).$ The problem is that $uv\Big|_0^{\infty}$ diverges. In fact, no choice for $dv$ seems to work because we have $y, y' \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty,$ which means the boundary term will never behave well. If we had $\frac{1}{y}$ instead, then the boundary terms would not be a problem at all.

Another natural approach is to find a series for $y.$ However, I already have the series: $y = \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} \frac{(x/2)^{2n}}{(n!)^2}.$ In fact, I started with the series and found the differential equation. Going back to the series would basically mean starting over, but perhaps it is necessary to start over. However, what would you do with the series? You can't rearrange the summation and integration signs because $\int_0^{\infty} x^n \cos(x/\sqrt{2}) \, dx$ diverges. All of the terms have to be treated as a whole, and I'm not sure how you would do that.

Any approaches, hints, or ideas? This is beginning to look like quite a tricky problem.

Update: I made a mistake when reducing the problem, and we should have $\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^2/2}y \, dx.$ I will post a solution for this modified version.

Comment: I don't think the integral is convergent.

Comment: Why do you have $y,y'\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: @Andrei For $x>0,$ we have $y > 1 + (x/2)^2/1! = 1+x^2/4.$

Answer (score 1):

Solution to the modified version: Let $I_n = \int_0^{\infty} x^{2n+1} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx.$ Reversing the order of summation and integration, we have $\int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^2/2} y \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^2/2} \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} \frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2} = \sum\limits_{n \ge 0} \frac{I_n}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}.$

$I_0 = \int_0^{\infty} xe^{-x^2/2} \, dx = -e^{-x^2/2} \big|_0^{\infty} = 1,$ and for $n \ge 1, I_n = -\int_0^{\infty} x^{2n} d(e^{-x^2/2}) = -x^{2n} e^{-x^2/2}\big|_0^{\infty} + \int_0^{\infty} 2nx^{2n-1}e^{-x^2/2} \, dx = 2nI_{n-1},$ so $I_n = 2n \cdot (2n-2) \cdots 2 = 2^n n!$ and the summation is nothing but $\sum\limits_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{2^n n!} = e^{1/2}.$